# How to do a camera filters with flutter?

Tags: flutter, filter, camera, real-time

How can I implement a real-time camera filter in Flutter?

Answer (score 5):

There is no method or an object in the camera plugin that can do this task. But I think you can do this effect by wrapping the CameraPreview Widget in a ShaderMask Widget . Then you can add filters by by using a LinearGradient Widget and your custom colours in the 
shaderCallBack Method and enhance it by specifying a BlendMode in the blendmode named parameter .

Comment: Then how can I save that image with shadermask?
I have tried but its only saving gradient not the camera view